# exercise - help in debugging nested list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary like:

```
output = {'all_paths': [{'path': [{'to': '59v4aQo015zRyeGZ', 'proximity': 6, 'from': '4Po9aW3oxoNaAQzW'}], 'weight': 6}, {'path': [{'to': '59v4aQo015zRyeGZ', 'proximity': 7, 'from': 'AyD8rYemY6er47Vk'}, {'to': 'ZGmDayG795LRojPv', 'proximity': 6, 'from': 'AyD8rYemY6er47Vk'}, {'to': '59v4aQo015zRyeGZ', 'proximity': 6, 'from': '4Po9aW3oxoNaAQzW'}, {'to': 'ZGmDayG795LRojPv', 'proximity': 6, 'from': '4Po9aW3oxoNaAQzW'}, {'to': '59v4aQo015zRyeGZ', 'proximity': 6, 'from': 'eEo7aB0vgkdRO02V'}, {'to': 'ZGmDayG795LRojPv', 'proximity': 4, 'from': 'eEo7aB0vgkdRO02V'}], 'weight': 35}, {'path': [{'to': 'LWbARpjEjpZae3DZ', 'proximity': 4, 'from': '4Po9aW3oxoNaAQzW'}, {'to': '59v4aQo015zRyeGZ', 'proximity': 6, 'from': '4Po9aW3oxoNaAQzW'}], 'weight': 10}, {'path': [{'to': 'ZGmDayG795LRojPv', 'proximity': 6, 'from': '4Po9aW3oxoNaAQzW'}], 'weight': 6}, {'path': [{'to': 'LWbARpjEjpZae3DZ', 'proximity': 4, 'from': '4Po9aW3oxoNaAQzW'}], 'weight': 4}, {'path': [{'to': 'ZGmDayG795LRojPv', 'proximity': 7, 'from': 'LWbARpjEjpZae3DZ'}], 'weight': 7}]}
```

I want to create two sets, one containing all ids in field 'to', the other all ids in field 'from'.

I tried with list comprehension for brevity, but have an unexpected result, containing only one topic :

```
nf = set([edge['from'] for edge in path['path'] for path in output['all_paths']])
# set(['LWbARpjEjpZae3DZ'])
```

The correct result would be:

```
nf = set()
for edge in [path['path'] for path in output['all_paths']]:
    nf.add( edge[0]['from'])
# set(['AyD8rYemY6er47Vk', '4Po9aW3oxoNaAQzW', 'LWbARpjEjpZae3DZ'])
```

Could you help point out what is wrong with my nested list comprehension ?

Comment: You have to invert the two `for` clauses, ie : `[edge['from'] for path in output['all_paths'] for edge in path['path']]`. FWIW nested list comprehensions are unintuitive to write, difficult to understand and really a PITA to debug, so better avoid them and use a plain for loop instead.

Comment: The advantage is that comprehensions can be particularly fast but you need to make sure you understand how they operate. Lots of practice will help!

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment the best way to solve these problems is to follow an iterative search down the tree

Firstly, you'll see that there is one root key

```
In [212]: output.keys()
Out[212]: ['all_paths']
```

Then you can look at the type of this to see it must be iterated

```
In [222]: type(output['all_paths'])
Out[222]: list
```

Then we can look at the available keys in each list item to see that `path, weight` are keys

```
In [223]: set(tuple(i.keys()) for i in output['all_paths'])
Out[223]: {('path', 'weight')}
```

Then look at `path` to find the next level of key

```
In [217]: set(tuple(j.keys()) for i in output['all_paths'] for j in i['path'])
Out[217]: {('to', 'proximity', 'from')}
```

and we can build up our comprehension

```
In [220]: set(j.get('from') for i in output['all_paths'] for j in i.get('path', []))
Out[220]:
{'4Po9aW3oxoNaAQzW',
 'AyD8rYemY6er47Vk',
 'LWbARpjEjpZae3DZ',
 'eEo7aB0vgkdRO02V'}

In [221]: set(j.get('to') for i in output['all_paths'] for j in i.get('path', []))
Out[221]: {'59v4aQo015zRyeGZ', 'LWbARpjEjpZae3DZ', 'ZGmDayG795LRojPv'}
```

Notice that I use `i.get('path', [])` this will mean that if the key isn't present nothing will break and no items will be appended to the `set`.

More generally, remember that the comprehension is a collapsed form of

```
s = set()
for i in output['all_paths']: # start here
    for j in i['path']:       # this line next in comprehension
        j.get('to')           # the result goes to the front
        s.add(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested comprehension:

```
d = {i.get('from', i.get('id')) for b in output['all_paths'] for i in b['path']}
```

Output:

```
{'LWbARpjEjpZae3DZ', 'eEo7aB0vgkdRO02V', 'AyD8rYemY6er47Vk', '4Po9aW3oxoNaAQzW'}
```